# Fuseki failed uploading my protege data, keep giving me errors

Tags: jena, owl, fuseki

I am trying to upload my ontology that I built using protege version 5.2.0 to Apache Jena Fuseki server

I save the file in .ttl format and when I tried uploading it I got

> Result: failed with message "Parse error: [line: 1765, col: 3 ]
>   Triples not terminated by DOT"

what I have in line 1765 is

> rdfs:label "Sequence accession", "sequence accession"@en .

Here is few lines in my .ttl file around line 1765

> ns0:IAO_0000412 "EDAM" ;   ns1:hasDefinition "A persistent, unique
>   identifier of a molecular sequence database entry." ;
>   ns1:hasExactSynonym "Sequence accession number" ;   ns1:inSubset
>   ns0:edam#data, ns0:edam#edam, ns0:edam#identifiers ;   rdfs:label
>   "Sequence accession", "sequence accession"@en .
>
> ns0:BFO_0000001   a owl:Class ;   rdfs:subClassOf owl:Thing ;

I then tried saving the file in OWL/XML format and I got

Result: failed with message "Parse error: [line: 20, col: 88] {E201} Multiple children of property element"

So I keep getting syntax error with every format I tried to upload

any suggestions in how to fix that ??

Many Thanks

Comment: OWL/XML is not the same as OWL mapped to RDF and then serialized in RDF/XML. OWL/XML is *not* an RDF syntax.  It's probably better to post the part of your Turtle file around lin 1765 and see if you can identify the missing DOT.

Comment: -rdfs:label "Sequence accession", "sequence accession"@en . this is how line 1675, in this case I guess I will be getting errors in my file even if I fixed this one, can you suggest a better way to upload protege data into Fuseki?

Comment: that should not happen. Which Protege version do you use? If it generates illegal Turtle, we might open a ticket for OWL API.

Comment: And can you please post some (3 to 5) lines before and after the line as well. And please add it to your question, it's unreadable in comments. That said, you can also try to save the ontology as `RDF/XML` - Fuseki is able to load this format, it just can't handle `OWL/XML`

Comment: The String literal with the line break is invalid in Turtle. It would have to be wrapped inside triple quotes, e.g. """ this is multiline text """. Please update Protege 5.5 first, then try again. If that doesn't work use RDF/XML, not OWL/XML